# Relation between a graph and the unit disk

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

It is well-known that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=\pi$$

Since $\pi$ is also the area of the unit disk, there may exist an area-preserving mapping between the unit disk and

$$D=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, 0 \leq y\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right\}$$

What I mean by "area-preserving" is that for any measurable $C$ set of $D$, $C$ and its image in the disk have the same area.

I have two questions :

1. Does there exist one such mapping ?
2. If so, can we find an explicit expression ?

Comment: A differentiable $\phi:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ is area preserving if the determinant of $\phi'(x, y) $ is $1$ for all $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: How nice do you want your map to be? Here are some thoughts: (1) By the Riemann mapping theorem you always find biholomorphic maps between the two sets. But they can never be area preserving  (assume $D$ open for this purpose and let $f=u+iv\colon \mathrm{Disk} \rightarrow D$ such a map. Show that $\nabla u$ is unbounded and that $\det Df = \vert \nabla u \vert^2$, then use the previous comment.) (2) If you're interested in arbitrary measurable maps, then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280608/constructing-measure-preserving-maps-between-non-atomic-measures) might be helpful.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982828/measure-preserving-maps-on-probability-spaces) is another related question. It does not have an answer, but someone in the comments outlines a to proof  (I have not tried to verify this though).